# google Drive SDK V2 Chidren List no subfolder

Tags: google-drive-api

In need to list files and folders inside a given folder, but not sub files and not sub folders.

So i use:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list

but it would appear to return all files in all subfolders.

I don't see an option for limiting to one level.
how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query - `q` - parameter - [see documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) - as follows.

Setting `q` to:

```
'xyz' in parents
```

Where `xyz` is the ID of the folder in question, will limit the results only to *direct* descendants of the folder.